# Applying a dynamic number of fields to a DataView.RowFilter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, rowfilter

All of the variables are here, I'm just not what the syntax should be.

I'm trying to create a drop down searchbox filter. The search box fields are dynamically populated using the code below

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Vwr.Table.Vals, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Col}" Style="{StaticResource tabTextBlock}"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Val}" Style="{StaticResource tabTextBox}" Width="200"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CTStr}" Style="{StaticResource tabTextBlock}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

**Col** : the column name

**Val** : the value inside of the textbox

**CTStr** : The dataType

---

The syntax for a RowFilter in c# is something like below ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter(v=vs.110).aspx))

"**Col** LIKE '%" + **Val** + "%' + " AND " + "**Col** LIKE '%" + **Val** + "%' 
 ... "

So what i need to do, is call an ICommand that launches whenever one of these dynamically generated textfields is updated, that when called checks to see the current RowFilter string, then, if it already has a field filtering in it appends AND and then it's own filter string.

Would it be possible to set the textbox to launch an ICommand with Col and the value inside of the textbox as command parameters anytime the user edits the textbox field?

Comment: Why don't you invoke the command from the setter of the Val property?

Comment: because the DataView is inside of Vwr.Table's viewmodel, not Vals,

Trying to do this gives me an error about two way Text="{Binding Val, Source=Vwr.Table, Mode=Default, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

Comment: Handle the TextChanged event then.